# Implementing different material themes to app. Based on material design owl app

Tags: android, material-design

Following this sample [Material Design Owl app design](https://material.io/design/material-studies/owl.html#) There is Personalize screen with yellow theme, Browse screen with blue theme and Learn screen with dark theme, like below:

[image]

My question is should I implement 3 activities for selected screens? Or should I implement different themes per Fragment?

I prefer one Activity with jetpack navigation, but is it possible to set theme for specific Fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Setting Theme in manifest is usually used for Activity.

If you want to set Theme for Fragment, add next code in the onCreateView() of the Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // create ContextThemeWrapper from the original Activity Context with the custom theme
    final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourCustomTheme);

    // clone the inflater using the ContextThemeWrapper
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);

    // inflate the layout using the cloned inflater, not default inflater
    return localInflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, container, false);
}
```

This would be worked on With classic Fragment within Activity.

Comment: but it will apply theme only to Fragment, not to Activity and action bar

Comment: you can set the default color to action bar in the fragment.